# QtCreator in Debug Error: LocalStorage: can't create path

Tags: sqlite, qt, remote-debugging

I'm having the following problem when I try to cross-debug my application in QtCreator 5.14 with SQLite :

```
Remote debugging from host 192.168.200.3
Process /home/pi/App_4/App_4 created; pid = 2327
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-pi'
QML Debugger: Waiting for connection on port 10001...
 Offline storage path :  "//.local/share/App_4/QML/OfflineStorage"
qml: Initializing database
qrc:/DataBase.js:4: Error: LocalStorage: can't create path /.local/share/App_4/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases
Detaching from process 2333
```

Where the DataBase.js file's first lines (the last line is line 4) are:

```
function dbInit() {
    console.log("Initializing database")

    db = LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("appDB", "1.0", "App database", 100000);
```

This is strange because when I run (NOT debug) the application (from host PC or from target (Raspberry pi 4)) the database is created and perfectly working at the standard path:

```
home/pi/.local/share/App_4/QML/OfflineStorage/Databases
```

with read and write permissions for all.
The main.cpp is the following:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QDebug>
#include "cppworker.h"
#include "objectdevicecreator.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    CppWorker worker;
    ObjectDeviceCreator deviceCreator;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qDebug() << " Offline storage path : " << engine.offlineStoragePath();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("BWorker", &worker);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ObjectDevice", &deviceCreator);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

P.S.: i'm connecting to the host by means of SSH, host is VirtualBox running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with static IP and target is Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian with static IP also.

Comment: Which version of Qt you are using? Maybe in Debug mode your system runs application in some kind of sandbox. Antivirus's also can block access. Have you tried using c++ SQLite? And how much you need data to save in db, maybe settings could be better?

Comment: @BrutalWizard as I said the version is 5.14, my host system is a VirtualBox that runs Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Which differences are in c++ SQLite from SQLite (it's the first time I use SQLite) ?

Comment: I asked about Qt version, not Qt Creator version.) No difference, in C++ u're just doing all by yourself. So, maybe if u do it through C++ you will not have this issues or if you have small data to save, you could use [Settings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html)